# Get unexpected result of `train_function` || Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

**!! I know there are a lot of similar questions. But somehow I can't find the right answer !!**

I am currently writing a model based on a dataset that has the different chess moves of a game. The aim is to have a kind of chess AI that you could play against. So far so good. However, now I encounter the following error when I try to train the model:

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information about where went wrong, or file an issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

First, I followed the instructions in the error and added this `run_eagerly=True` to the compile function but this didn't do anything.

Then I googled and found some other Stackoverflow questions where they mentioned the problem is with the Conv2D layers:

```py
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_board)
[...]
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
[...]
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
[...]
```

I don't really find a good answer to my problem. Here is my Notebook:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/fabboy/chessai/notebook

Thank you for your help